# What is the best size for video which can fit for all mobile screens?

Tags: android, video, exoplayer

**What would be the best size or scale of height and width for video which can fit for all mobile screens properly.**

Answer (score 0):

For mobile the best size is for all smartphones is 1080X1090 pixels.For 1080X1090 pixels in height and width is 3.6 X 3.63 Inches OR 91.44 X 92.29 Millimeters this is for 300 resolution